# X and Y value to Vector2

Tags: xna, c#

In the first code I get a Vector2 random position and create an object with that, but in the second code I want to use the same constructor to create an object, but I want to pass a X and Y value to the constructor, that expects a Vector2 value.

```
Vector2 newPosition = NewRandomPosition;    
listTools.Add(new Tool(content, tools[i], newPosition));
```

I thought I could do something like this, but it didn't work!

```
int x = 30, y = 22;
listJunk.Add(new Junk(content, "junk", (x,y)));
```

Is there another way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a `Vector2` from the `x` and `y` values before using it. For example:

```
listJunk.Add(new Junk(content, "junk", new Vector2(x,y)));
```

Comment: Beat me to it by a few seconds.

Comment: Indeed, it was a matter of seconds lol :P

Answer (score 3):

Use a Vector2 object like this:

```
listJunk.Add(new Junk(content, "junk", new Vector2(x,y)));
```